# Nodejs, mongodb, authentication, on different server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my situation:
I deploy my application on server A;
And I deployed my mongodb on server B;
the mongodb is secured by authentication. I know that I  have to connect like:

```
mongo IP_ADDRESS/testDB -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

So my problem is:

```
mongoClient = require("mongo").MongoClient;<br>
    url = "mongodb://username:password@IP_ADDRESS:27017/testDB"
```

when I am using to the username has the role of **root**, and with this URL, I can only access the database of admin, no more others.
anyone help!

Comment: Are you able to login to MongoDB database and check the other existing databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user exists only in admin db obviously, so you have to provide authsource to mongoClient.connect. this is not connecting database, only for authentication. 
Example for your situation is:

```
mongoClient = require("mongo").MongoClient; 
url = "mongodb://username:password@IP_ADDRESS:27017/testDB?authSource=admin
```

here is the documentation for url parameters. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/#uri.authSource

Comment: yes, exactly, I didnt read thought thoroughly and I really should do so.